# Select a TabPage by its Label/Text

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, tabcontrol

I have the following code that creates a TabPage with Text `tab1`:

```
string tabTitle = "tab1";
TabPage createdtabpage = new TabPage(tabTitle);
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(createdtabpage);
```

I want to get a TabPage using the string that I've set and then select it.  Maybe something like this:

```
 //this will select the tab that has a title of "tab1"
 this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.getTabByTitle(tabTitle);
```

Is there a way to accomplish something like that?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assign the same value to the `TabPage.Text` property and `TabPage.Name` property, in case the assigned Text is compatible with Name property constraint (as it would be when the Text is `"tab1"`, as shown in the question), then simply select the TabPage by its name:

```
string tabTitle = "tab1";
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage(tabTitle));

// [...]

tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[tabTitle];
```

If the Text is not *compatible* (as `"This is TabPage1"`), then you can use LINQ's [OfType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype) to select a TabPage that has the Text specified:

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages.OfType<TabPage>()
    .FirstOrDefault(tp => tp.Text == tabTitle);
```

In this case, if the TabPage is not found, [FirstOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) will return `null` and the TabControl will show no TabPage selected in the UI.